# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nomEtatAvancement' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been battling with this block of code and I get :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nomEtatAvancement' of undefined

**etat-avancement.component.ts**

```ts
export class EtatAvancementComponent {

  settings = {
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
      nom_etat_avancement: {
        title: 'Nom D\'Etat D\'Avancement',
        type: 'string',
      },
      descri_avanacement: {
        title: 'Description Etat D\'Avancement',
        type: 'string',
      },
    },
  };

  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
  etat: any = [];

  constructor(private service: SmartTableData, public rest: RestService) {

    this.rest.getEtatAvancements().subscribe((data: any) => {
      let i = 0;
      for (let dataKey in data) {
        this.etat.push({
          "nom_etat_avancement": data["content"][i].nomEtatAvancement,
          "descri_avanacement": data["content"][i].descriAvanacement
        });
        i++;
      }
      console.log(this.etat);
      this.source.load(this.etat);
    });
  }
```

This is the result of the angular service in the browser console :

```
{links: Array(2), content: Array(1), page: {…}}
content: Array(1)
0: {nomEtatAvancement: "En Cours", descriAvanacement: "Ce projet est en cours de réalisation.", content: Array(0), links: Array(6)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
links: (2) [{…}, {…}]
page: {size: 20, totalElements: 1, totalPages: 1, number: 0}
__proto__: Object
```

and it is correct.

Comment: avoid using the constructor for anything expect Dependancy Injection. Try placing your code into the ngOnInit lifecycle hook.

Comment: you can debug that in your browser! i suggest you to using chrome

Comment: Welcome to SO Mohamed, please stop coding in french =D

Answer (score 0):

`for (let dataKey in data)` iterates on `data`'s properties: `links`, `content`, `page`, so it exceeds length of `data.content`.

Use `data.content.forEach` (if you want to preserve previous data in `this.etat`) or `data.content.map` (if `this.etat` should contain only elements from current response) as in snippet below (replace `etat1` or `etat2` with `this.etat`)

```js
let data = {
  links: ["link1", "link2"],
  content: [{
    nomEtatAvancement: "En Cours",
    descriAvanacement: "Ce projet est en cours de réalisation.",
    content: [],
    links: [ /*some 6 links*/ ]
  }],
  page: {}
};

//you're doing this:
let i = 0;
for (let dataKey in data) {
  console.log("dataKey = ", dataKey, '; data["content"][i] =', data["content"][i]);
  i++;
}


//do this to append some values to existing array, leaving previous content
let etat1 = [];

data.content.forEach(content => {
  etat1.push({
    nom_etat_avancement: content.nomEtatAvancement,
    descri_avanacement: content.descriAvanacement
  })
})

console.log("etat1:", etat1);

//do this to replace your array with data from data.content
let etat2 = data.content.map(content => ({
    nom_etat_avancement: content.nomEtatAvancement,
    descri_avanacement: content.descriAvanacement
  })
)

console.log("etat2:", etat2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help,I changed my code to be like this and it works good :

```
source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
  etat: any = [] ;

  constructor(private service: SmartTableData ,  public rest:RestService) {

      this.rest.getEtatAvancements().subscribe((data:any) =>{

     data.content.forEach((key: any , val: any)=>{
        this.etat.push({"nom_etat_avancement" : data["content"][val].nomEtatAvancement , "descri_avanacement" : data["content"][val].descriAvanacement});
      });
        this.source.load(this.etat);
    });
```